# how to active domain class in jar package?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I using GORM in spring boot application.
When i put some domain class in Jar package, application couldn't realize it.

```
@Entity
class Book implements GormEntity<Book>{
  String title
}
```

How to active domain class in jar package?

Comment: Not really sure that you can use GORM in a jar. ¿Shouldn't it be a plugin instead?

Answer (score 0):

use @ComponentScan in Application class could find all domain class deploy in jar package.